# Cannot get spinner to work in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am having great difficulty understanding how to code a spinner. I've looked at the many items on this site and others but don't understand why it has to be SO complicated, with some solutions even involving creating a class. All I want to be able to do is, when the user selects one of the items from the spinner drop-down, which one has been clicked needs to be identified then the code triggers a new activity or a method or some other action.
The web site I-Programmer seemed to offer a relatively simple solution and I have followed the coding instructions to the letter but it doesn't work. I have written to them but they haven't replied yet.
Their code now follows, but I don't understand how it can work, as there doesn't seem to be a link between the AdapterView block and the actual spinner stuff before it. It doesn't compile as is. When I add a few semi-colons and braces, it DOES compile but still doesn't work.
Can anyone sort it out for me please?

```
package com.example.owner.spinners;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] country = {"Canada", "Mexico", "USA"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter=
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    country);

    Spinner spinner=
            (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
}

AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onSpinner=
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){  // Error 1 here
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onSpinner =
                    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(
                                AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view,
                                int position,
                                long id) {  // Does my 'if' code go here?
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(
                                AdapterView<?>  parent) {  // and here?
                        }
                    } // Error 2 here. ; expected
        } // Error 3 here. ; expected

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{  
    ...
}
```

Error 1 reads, Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnItemSelectedListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onNothingSelected (AdapterView)' in 'OnItemSelectedListener' I'm afraid I don't follow all that. I have really tried.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out this example: [spinner example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm)

Comment: Thank you, Cylon. But again, that example seems over-complicated, with pages and pages of code. I think I need to do some serious learning before I get to grips with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, why you have a compile error:

- Error 1 - because you tried create a variable in this place, but you can't do that. In this place you can use a existing variable/field or create a simple anonymous class.
- Error 2 - compiler expected `;` because you are ended of the part of code, so you have to end this by `;`.
- Error 3 - it the same situation like in Error 2.

So, I a little improved your code and added some comments. I hope now the code is more understandable for you.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // create a adapter
    String[] country = {"Canada", "Mexico", "USA"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, country);

    // create a spinner
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    // add adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
    // create listener and add to spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // put code which recognize a selected element
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am most grateful to you, Mateusz. Your comments in the code are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an extra class, you can use an [anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Be sure to register the Listener to your spinner.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String[] country = {"Canada", "Mexico", "USA"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter=  new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, country);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() // register the listener
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            // User selected item
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), country[position] + " selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I agree that anonymous inner classes CAN be great, but with android they face issues. For something simple like this, as long as the class doesn't take up ~50%+ of the LoC of the outer class, then 'sure' use an anon inner class. But if it 'feels like it is getting too complicated' then making it an external class can help clean up both files. more below...

Comment: The 'reason' why anon inner classes face issues in Android is whenever they are used by background threads. That is because java gives a hidden reference to the outer class to all non-static inner classes (anon too), so you can get a memory leak in Android when the foreground 'should' be GC'd, but isn't b/c a child thread contains a reference to the outer context. External classes actually 'fix' this problem, so there is a time/place for both solutions, just need to know when to use external class and/or anon inner class (sorry for 2nd comment was too long otherwise)

Comment: Thank you very much dkarnutsch, and of course, your code works like a dream. Thank you too, mawalker for your comments. It'll take me a while to fully understand what you have said but I'm sure I'll make it in the end.